# javascript load info function using a form to direct to another webpage

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code for a dropdown form that when the user clicks on a selection it should redirect to another local in folder document.

vvv this function is in my script and I have 3 other functions in my script that work properly except this one.

```
function loadInfo(myForm) {
var menuSelect=myForm.Menu.SelectedIndex
var menuURL=myForm.Menu.options[menuSelect].value+".html"
window.location=menuURL
}
```

vvv This form is in my body and it shows the drop down but there is no redirecting to the local document when a selection is made.

```
<form id="menu">
<p style="font-weight:bolder">
If your pencil was a Super Hero who would they be?
<select name="Menu" onchange="loadInfo(this.form)">
<option>Select an item</option>
<option value="batman">Batman</option>
<option value="superman">Superman</option>
<option value="hulk">Hulk</option>
<option value="wonder">Wonder Woman</option>
</select>
</p></form>
```

I am doing a mock website for school that requires this form function and there is only one decent example in my book but even that will not output the desired task I want to accomplish(also this code was taken from that example in the book. I have tried to put in some of my code with no results)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.selectedIndex
```

instead of

```
.SelectedIndex
```